# Create and assign multiple new dataframe columns in ifelse statement?

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe, dplyr

So I have a data frame `my_df` as follows

```
my_df <- data.frame(c("0600", "0602", "0603"))
```

Now I need to write `ifelse` statement which calculates 3 more variables and append it to a new data frame.

I am not able to find out on how to add multiple executable statements in the loop and append the calculated variables to a new data frame.

Below is my code for `ifelse` statement.

```
with(my_df, ifelse(my_df$H == "0600",{d$D <- 1+1 & d$c <- "0600"},
    ifelse(my_df$H == "0602",{d$D <- 2+1 & d$c <- "0602"},
        { d$D <- 3+1 & d$c <- "0603"}
)))
```

I am able to append values to new dataframe with only one executable code inside the `ifloop` i.e if I have only `{d$D <- 1+1}` it works perfectly but fails when I have multiple statements to execute.

My output data frame should be as shown below,

```
D    C
2    0600
3    0602
4    0603
```

Comment: `ifelse()` is a function. ... and you are not saving the result of the function.

Comment: @jogo Yeah I know that. So what changes will you suggest me to do so that it works?

Comment: FYI when you use `with(df,...)` you do not need to re-call the df to call its variables, i.e. `with(df, ifelse(H == ...))`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax for `ifelse` is off, but I would recommend using `case_when` from the `dplyr` library here:

```
library(dplyr)
d$D <- case_when(
    my_df$H == "0600" ~ 1+1,
    my_df$H == "0602" ~ 2+1,
    TRUE ~ 3+1
)

d$c <- case_when(
    my_df$H == "0600" ~ "0600",
    my_df$H == "0602" ~ "0602",
    TRUE ~ "0603"
)
```

You could also use `ifelse`, but you would need nested calls to `ifelse` and it probably would not look good, or be very maintainable.

Comment: I tried reproducing your solution and it works perfectly for the question asked, but here is my doubt. I also tried to add an equation in place of arithmetic operation like in the line `my_df$H == "0600" ~ 1+1` I replaced it with this line `my_df$H == "0600" ~ substr(my_df$H,1,3)`. This is not working, can you please let me know where am I going wrong.

Comment: @ANmike You should ask a new question.  My guess is the API does not allow function calls as predicates, but you may easily enough workaround this.

Comment: I am sorry, I will post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

**Using Base R**

```
my_df <- data.frame("C" = c("0600", "0602", "0603"))
my_df$D  <- ifelse(my_df$C=="0600",2,ifelse(my_df$C=="0602",3,ifelse(my_df$C=="0603",4,NA)))
```

Comment: Down voter, I appreciate if you can explain why the down vote.

Comment: I countered your downvote, but most likely his reason is that while your answer technically exactly matches what the OP asked for, it isn't best coding practice to have a large nested `ifelse` call.

Comment: @jogo technically my code is the only output containing C and D as per OP output.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thank you for your kind action and advise. But the OP ask for nested ifelse.

Comment: I understand that, but for next time keep in mind that SO is also about the _best_ answer, not just what the OP asked for.  Case in point, often people ask for regex solutions to parsing HTML and XML, and we don't encourage this.

Comment: @A.Suliman o.k., it is not clear from the question, because the code in the question is manipulating the original dataframe. I retracted my downvote.

Comment: @jogo as per OP question "My output data frame should be as shown below,". Please read the question carefully

Comment: @A.Suliman Yes, I read especially the code in the question. There is a contradiction between the described output and what the code should do.

Answer (score 1):

Using a list:

```
# My data frame
my_df <- data.frame(H = c("0600", "0602", "0603"))

# My list to be used as a lookup
my_list <- list("0600" = c(D = 2, C = "0600"),
                "0602" = c(D = 3, C = "0602"),
                "0604" = c(D = 4, C = "0603"))

# Find corresponding values for 'H' 
# Then bind into a data frame
do.call(bind_rows, my_list[my_df$H])
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#   D     C    
# <chr> <chr>
# 1 2     0600 
# 2 3     0602 
# 3 4     0603
```