# Expressions in case_when statement in R

Tags: r, dataframe

My question is based on the [question asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50153737/multiple-expressions-in-ifelse-statement/50153834?noredirect=1#comment87352627_50153834) for `Multiple expression in ifelse() statement`. I need to have an `expression` instead of Arithmetic Operation inside the case_when() function. Below is my data frame

```
my_df <- data.frame(H= c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI"))
```

So here is my code to where I tried to add an expression inside the `case_when()` but it does not work.

```
library(dplyr)
output_df$D <- case_when(
  my_df$H == "ABC" ~ substr(my_df$H,1,3),
  my_df$H == "DEF" ~ substr(my_df$H,1,2),
  TRUE ~ substr(my_df$H,1,1)
 )
```

My expected output dataframe is:

`output_df`

```
   D  
  ABC  
  DE  
  G
```

Comment: The code is working fine for me.  Do you have a data.frame `output_df` ?  Suppose, if I assign the output to `my_df$D <- ` it works fine

Comment: @akrun No I get an error `Error: must be type character, not double`

Comment: You  have a factor column, but it is working fine for me with the version I have

Comment: I am using `dplyr_0.7.4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear about the error (in the comments) as the code runs fine although 'H' is a a `factor` class.  One thing, we can do is to convert the 'D' to `character` class (`as.character`) before doing the `case_when`

```
library(tidyverse)
output_df <- my_df %>%
               mutate(D = as.character(D)) %>%
               transmute(D = case_when(H=="ABC" ~ substr(H, 1, 3), 
                        H=="DEF" ~ substr(H, 1, 2), 
                        TRUE ~ substr(H, 1, 1)))
output_df
#    D
#1 ABC
#2  DE
#3   G
```

---

Or better would be to use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in `data.frame` call

```
my_df <- data.frame(H= c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Or use `data_frame` or `tibble` to create the dataset that by default gives `character` class for non-numeric column

```
my_df <- data_frame(H= c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI"))
```